# To run the tabulate and which.max function in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a DataFrame `data` in sparkR. It contains `user = 12 311 12 320, ...` and `type = 1 2 3 4`. We have 10000 user's.

For example one user have type = 1 2 3 4 4 4 2 4.
I want to find the most common integer in type for this user. In R I can solve it this way

```
mostcommon <- which.max(tabulate(user$type))
```

given that 'user' was a data.frame and not a DataFrame.
I want do this for all user's in 'data'. One way to do this is this way

```
u<- c()
for(j in 1:10000) {
id <- filter(data, data$user== j)
# For the jth user I make the data local to run the 
# which.max and tabulate functions
idlocal <- collect(id)
u[j] <- which.max(tabulate(idlocal$type))
}
```

This runs in R/sparkR and u gives me the most common type for all user's. But it takes time because I maked the data local to run the which.max and tabulate functions. Is there a smarter and more fast way to do this?

Futhermore how could one find the two most common types as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works:

Create example data

```
localData <- data.frame(user = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                        type = c(1,2,2,3,3,2))

data <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, localData)
```

Group by user and type and count how many times it occurs (sort of tabulate)

```
groupedData <- groupBy(data, data$user, data$type)
aggregated  <- agg(groupedData, number = n(data$user))
```

Order on this counted number, since this is the easiest way to find the type which has a maximal occurrence.

```
arranged <- arrange(aggregated, desc(aggregated$number))
```

Group again on user and take the first occurrence of type, which is the maximum since we have ordered it.

```
regroupedData <- groupBy(arranged, arranged$user)
firstItems    <- agg(regroupedData, firstType = first(arranged$type), number = first(arranged$number))
```

Check out the results

```
collect(firstItems)
```

If you now want the second most occurring item as well, you can first delete these first items

```
firstDeleted <- except(arranged,firstItems)
```

And apply the same method again

```
rearranged   <- arrange(firstDeleted, desc(firstDeleted$number))

reregroupedData <- groupBy(rearranged, rearranged$user)
secondItems     <- agg(reregroupedData, secondType = first(rearranged$type))
```

Delete non necessary column and rename a column
firstItems$number  <- NULL
secondItems        <- withColumnRenamed(secondItems, "user", "user2")

For the final result, join these DataFrames (en delete column user2)

```
result <- join(firstItems,secondItems, firstItems$user == secondItems$user2)

result$user2 <- NULL
```

And again to check these results

```
collect(result)
```

Comment: Say we want the two most common types how should one do that? Maybe by remove the first(arranged$type) and then take the first again.

Comment: You want for every user the first two types?

Comment: Yes the first two types which would be the most common types as well.

Comment: I have a working example, but it has too many characters to put in a comment. It's based on the except function. Could create a new or edit your question?

Comment: The line firstDeleted <- except(arranged,result). Should result be replaced with firstItems ?

Comment: Yes, changed it. Thanks

Comment: When I type collect(result) I only get one type shown - but it should show both types ?

Comment: It shows one type per row, but each user has two rows, hence two types.

Comment: Actualy, when you join rename the column of secondItems and you join firstItems and secondItems, you will probably get what you desire.

Comment: When I type head(filter(firstItems, firstItems$user_id==1)) I get user_id=8966 and type=4 and number=1. When I type head(filter(secondItems, secondItems$user_id==1)) I get user_id=8966 and type=4. When I type head(result) the first row is user_id=8966 and type=4. But 'result' should contain two types in the first row.

Comment: Now both top results are present, I didn't add the number they occur anymore, but this is still possible.